# Orthonormalization of infinite basis

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If we have an infinite $L^2$ basis that is determined by the eigenfunctions of the eigenvalue problem $$ -\Delta \psi=\lambda \psi$$

How can we orthonormalize this basis with respect to the $H^1_0$ inner product $(\nabla \cdot, \nabla \cdot)$? Or why is this orthonormalization possible ?

Comment: Regardless of the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$, if you have an orthogonal basis $\{ f_n \}$, then $\{\frac{1}{(f_n,f_n)^{1/2}}f_n \}$ is an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts  even in infinite case?

Comment: Yes, even in the infinite case. Even regardless of the cardinality of the orthogonal basis. All you're doing is multiplying by scalars to make the vectors unit vectors.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts thanks a lot